# How to assign a percentage to a property of CSSStyleDeclaration

Tags: javascript, css, xulrunner

I work on an Eclipse RCP application having a HTML editor using XULRunner. In the JavaScript code interacting with the editor, I want to set the maximum width of an element using `CSSStyleDeclaration.maxWidth`:

```
/* node is an HTMLImageElement */
node.style.maxWidth = "100%";
```

The code above fails with the following message

```
Warning: Error in parsing value for property 'max-width'.  Declaration dropped.
```

But if I use pixels, it works:

```
node.style.maxWidth = "100px";
```

What is the correct syntax to set the CSS max-width property to 100%?

Comment: `maxWidth = "100%"` should work just fine (in a browser). Must be a XULRunner thing.

Comment: Did you try it without the quotation marks?

Comment: @DevlshOne: That would make it a JavaScript syntax error (the `%` would be the modulo operator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
node.style.maxWidth = '100%';
```

Comment: It works, indeed. Can you explain the difference between "100%" and '100%'?

Comment: Glad it worked, you never know how different browser interpret/parse your tags. Here the article helps to understand why it should be (See section 2.5. Property value examples) http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#component-types

Comment: @julien: There **must** have been some other problem. In JavaScript, strings can be quoted with either `"` or `'`. There is *zero* difference between `"100%"` and `'100%'`. Zero.

Comment: No difference in JavaScript but a difference in the application. As you have pointed before, it must be a XULrunner thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with the way you are declaring it. Your XULRunner must not be able to parse it properly.

Here are the official specs for [max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) as written by MDN